# Hiding duplicate links with aria-hidden

Tags: accessibility

I know that in theory you shouldn't hide active elements... But... What if the link is repeated twice?

To clarify the link is on the picture which has no additional information value. A separate link is on a text and the url is the same as on the picture. The problem is that the picture is a separate component for the text link. So I can only surround the picture with an element (div). I have limited options to change the structure of the picture component.

It seems to me that the UX of a person with a screen reader will be better if redundant links are hidden. Formally, however, it is not recommended. Not sure what to do?

Rough structure is something like this:

```
<div role="listitem">
 <div aria-hidden="true">
  <fileComponent name="Wikipedia-logo.png" link="w:Some article"/>
 </div>
 <p>
  <linkComponent url="w:Some article" label="Wikipedia"/>
 </p>
</div>
```

I have the option to add `alt` to `fileComponent`, but not more advanced attributes.

PS: To give more context... Actual code is from Wikipedia. And to clarify I do want links on both the image and text.

```
<div role="listitem">
<div aria-hidden="true">[[Plik:Wikipedia-logo.png|50px|link=w:]]</div>
<p>[[w:|'''Wikipedia''']]</p>
</div>
<div role="listitem">
<div aria-hidden="true">[[Plik:Wikiquote-logo.svg|50px|link=q:]]</div>
<p>[[q:|'''Wikiquote''']]</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aria-hidden` will indeed hide the element from screen readers and will prevent the user from navigating to it **with the screen reader** (such as using the down arrow) but does **not** prevent the user from navigating to it with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key (since links are inherently keyboard focusable). This means a screen reader user could <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the hidden link but nothing will be announced because the element was removed from the [accessibility tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.2/#dfn-accessibility-tree).

That's bad.

To prevent <kbd>TAB</kbd>, you'd need `tabindex="-1"`.  However, that will prevent sighted keyboard users from navigating to it.  That might be a good thing as you'll have fewer tab stops, but if something looks like a link, then I'd expect to be able to <kbd>TAB</kbd> to it.

It's always best to reduce/eliminate duplicate links, especially when they're next to each other in the DOM, but that's mainly a best practice and doesn't necessarily make for a horrible user experience (unless, I suppose, you have 50 links on the page and they're all duplicated).

Duplicate links are not a [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) failure.

I commend you for trying to make the UX better for some users but this is a case where you don't really have to "fix" it.  Screen reader users have [lots of shortcut keys](https://www.freedomscientific.com/training/jaws/hotkeys/) for navigating the page.  Interestingly enough, navigating with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is **not** the most common way to navigate, so many screen reader users will **not** run into the duplicate link problem.  They will often navigate with <kbd>G</kbd> to jump to each image ('graphic') or <kbd>U</kbd> to go to the next unvisited link (NVDA allows <kbd>K</kbd> to go to the next link).

Most screen readers allow the user to display a dialog with a list of links on the page.  You'd have duplicate links in that dialog if you don't hide the duplicate link.  If you can't change your page structure to combine the picture and the text into one link, then it's a UX you'll have to live with.  It's more of an annoyance rather than a blocking behavior, so that's a minor silver lining.

In general, you can't really hide an interactive element from *just* screen reader users.  In order to do so, you have to "hide" the <kbd>TAB</kbd> too, which makes it "hidden" for sighted keyboard users.

Answer (score 2):

To support screen readers, use [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) to provide an article description similar to the visual description the image provided.

Put `aria-label` attribute in the `role="listitem"` DIV:

```
<div aria-label="Describe the article in some detail." role="listitem">
 <div aria-hidden="true">
  <fileComponent name="Wikipedia-logo.png" alt="brief description of image" link="w:Some article"/>
 </div>
 <p>
  <linkComponent url="w:Some article" label="Wikipedia"/>
 </p>
</div>
```

(Unrelated to question but added `alt` attribute to `fileComponent`, which presents an image, for good measure.)

The `aria-hidden="true"` DIV—along with it the `fileComponent` tag—is hidden but the `role="listitem"` DIV presents the description provided in the `aria-label` attribute to the screen reader.

From [W3C Using ARIA, Practical Support: aria-label...](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support):

> Don't use aria-label or aria-labelledby on a span or div unless its
> given a role.

Since the `role="listitem"` DIV has a [role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles) `aria-label` is appropriate.

---

There are two approaches to consider here:

1. User-focused
2. Media-focused

**User-focuced**

The above example is user-focused—rather than merely describing the image, a textual description is designed and written to do the job of the image.

With a user-focus, media is selected, designed and developed according to the tools or inputs the user uses to access the information. Consider the various users you are presenting to and design and develop media "packages" tailored to each of their receptive capabilities.

If a conventional browser is the presentation device then text, images, animation, videos, audio can be use to present the information. When a screen reader is used you are relying on text being converted to speech to present the same information to the user.

By taking the user's perspective when developing the presentation you're not describing the image, but instead doing the job of the image with text.

**Media-focused**

Alternatively, wrap the `aria-hidden="true"` DIV with a [`role="img"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Img_role) DIV including a `aria-label` attribute:

```
<div role="listitem">
 <div role="img" aria-label="Detailed description of image—for screen readers.">
   <div aria-hidden="true">
    <fileComponent name="Wikipedia-logo.png" alt="Brief description of image—for browser preload, missing image, and other support tools." link="w:Some article"/>
   </div>
 </div>
 <p>
  <linkComponent url="w:Some article" label="Wikipedia"/>
 </p>
</div>
```

In this case, and admittedly being simpler and having lower development costs, is to develop the media for users with full, or slightly limited receptive capability such as color sensitivity, then provide alternative text descriptions for each media component to be read by the screen reader.

Comment: +1 for using image descriptions

Comment: @RouxMartin Thanks for the reminder, I added an `alt` attribute to the `fileComponent` tag also.

Comment: Interesting and detailed answer... But doesn't answer my question. Funny thing is that chatGpt gave me similar, wrong answer 

Comment: @Nux "Not sure what to do?" — Maybe I'm not clear; what is your question? And in what way does either code option not work for you?

Comment: @Nux Sometimes this happens because you're trying to fix the wrong problem - A well-described image would make it clear to users with accessibility needs why there appear to be two identical links. This would mean that you don't need to hide anything. You could also try wrapping both elements in a single link. As other contributors have pointed out (including yourself) hiding things is not the solution.

Comment: @RouxMartin This is a logo it is purely decorational. I think I mentioned this in my question. I don't want it to be visible to screen readers, I want it to be visible for sighted readers. It is recommended to hide decorative images e.g. by WAI: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles your answer makes things worse. 1. The readers learn about decorative image. 2. You are suggesting to describe linked image in alt. This is not recommended. When you want to use alt in a link you describe the link (the destination), not the image.

Comment: I do appreciate the effort, but I think your answer is misleading.

Comment: @Nux If it is a logo and has a link then it's not a decorative image - Decorative images are things that have no purpose on the page - like a gradient tint for a background or a box corner flourish. A logo helps to identify the page to the user and a link helps with navigation - therefore your logo with a link is not a purely decorative image.

Comment: @Nux Thanks for clarifying. I think I'm still missing something. In the first section of code I provided—the "user-focused" example—how does a screen reader learn about the description of the image? — The "media-focused" example does but it's a general example provided as a contrast to the recommended "user-focused" approach.

Comment: @Nux "...use alt in a link you describe the link..." I'm missing something here too. By "alt in a link" do you mean something like `<a alt="describe image" href="gohere.html">...` ? If so, where do you see that? The `alt` attribute is not allowed and has no effect there. — If you don't mean that, please elaborate. I'm not familiar with `fileComponent` and `linkCompontent`. Only place I can find them together is in the paper: [Building Tailorable Hypermedia Systems: the embedded-interpreter approach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275479153_Building_tailorable_hypermedia_systems).

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles See e.g. example 2 in WCAG H30. The alt attribute is on the image element but it must describe a parent link (if there is no other text). "Using the alt attribute for the img element to describe the purpose of a graphical link." https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html

Comment: @Nux I see what you're saying—when an image is wrapped by a link and there's no text in the link to describe the link, use the IMG `alt` attribute to describe the link, not to describe the image. That makes sense. — Question: does the `linkComponent` present the `label` attribute within the link tag block? If so, would you say that is sufficient to satisfy a text description of the link, even though there are actually two (identical) links? Particularly because the first (image) link is hidden from screen readers?